# C++ DirectX Headers

Tags: c++, header, directx

ID: QTCreator 2.1, QT 4.7.
Language: C++

I'm working on a program that requires me to take screen shots of DirectX. I have downloaded the SDK and found the necessary include files to access DirectX. After including that D3DX10.h header, I realized I need to include a lot more headers. So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to add DirectX capability without including a ton of headers?
2. How have people done this in the past without cluttering up their projects?
3. Should I try to compile the SDK into a dll and use that instead (or does it alrady exist and I didn't find it yet)?

I'm new to adding sdk's beyond what ever comes with my IDE so I have little experience in this area.

Thanks for the help,

Jec.

Comment: What do you mean take screenshots of directX? Like screenshots of a working directX program?

Comment: Actually under most circumstances people note down the XYZ SDK as a prerequisite, take a backup of the installer/archive for that SDK and then include one or more rather central headers from that SDK. Most people do not commit a whole SDK alongside their projects, although I have seen and heard some doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need that many headers..unless you're trying to do a lot. To make a very basic directX program, you should only need to include 1 or 2 directX header files.